# Extension methods for interfaces, which interface gets priority?

Tags: c#, extension-methods

If I have a type that implements multiple interfaces, and have multiple same-named extension methods for the interface types that my type implements, what determines which extension method gets used?

In the case of a `List<T>`, if I have extension methods for `ICollection<T>` and `IEnumerable<T>`, then `ICollection<T>` is taking priority. If I add another extension that takes `IList<T>`, then `IList<T>` is taking priority over the other two methods. I thought maybe the order they were declared in the class was why, but that's not the case as `IList<T>` comes after the other two in the class definition.

Here's code I used to test it out:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;
                    
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var myList = new List<int>();       
        myList.IsNullOrEmpty();  // IList is used
        
        // Layout for List<T> in constructor
        //
        // public class List<T> : 
        //    ICollection<T>,
        //    IEnumerable<T>,
        //    ...,
        //    IList<T>,
        //    ...
    }
}

public static class Extensions
{
    public static bool IsNullOrEmpty<T>(this ICollection<T> collection)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ICollection used.");
        return collection?.Count == 0;
    }

    public static bool IsNullOrEmpty<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("IEnumerable used.");     
        return enumerable == null || !enumerable.Any();
    }
    
    public static bool IsNullOrEmpty<T>(this IList<T> list)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("IList used.");       
        return list?.Count == 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: The more specific, the higher the priority. `IEnumerable<T>` is the base interface of all others, so the more similar the better. In other words: the overload that is "closest" to the actual argument is the winner. If you pass an `List<T>` the interface `IList<T>` is the closest.

Comment: The specific rules are defined in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#1264-overload-resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@TimSchmelter's comment on my question was the correct answer.

`IList<T>` implements `ICollection<T>` and `IEnumerable<T>`, so it takes priority over those. And, `ICollection<T>` implements `IEnumerable<T>`, so it takes priority over it.

[`IList<T>` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.ilist-1?view=net-7.0)

[`ICollection<T>` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.icollection-1?view=net-7.0)